# Android file chooser input type for image upload

Tags: android, filechooser

Open filechooser is a big problem for me and maybe for many others....there is a full solution to handle input type in android?The above code is working for version 3.0+ and 4.1 ...is not working for other version biger than 4.1...for weeks trying to find a solution but without success

```
   // For Android 3.0+
           public void openFileChooser( ValueCallback uploadMsg, String acceptType ) {
           mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
           Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
           i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
           i.setType("*/*");
           MyWb.this.startActivityForResult(
           Intent.createChooser(i, "File Browser"),
           FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
           }

        //For Android 4.1
           public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture){
               mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;  
               Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
               i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);  
               i.setType("image/*");  
               MyWb.this.startActivityForResult( Intent.createChooser( i, "File Chooser" ), MyWb.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE );

           }
```

Answer (score 0):

The below method is a more conventional way to choose an image from a file. The intent uses `onActivityResult()` to retrieve what the user chose.

First create the intent.

 
`// Creates an Intent to pick a photo
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);`

Then execute the intent:

`// ARGS: the intent, a key to access later
startActivityForResult(i, 1);`

You have to now set a `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` (detailed instructions available [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)).
Here is some sample code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        try {
            // Do whatever you want with this bitmap (image)
            Bitmap bitmapImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
            Log.i("Image Path", selectedImage.getPath());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Put the method directly into your class. You can now do whatever you want with the `Bitmap` that was received.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for android version 4.1+ the file chooser is not opening....